# how would I find and store only changes to an image

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm working on an image (photo) editing app using C++ and OpenCV 2.4.10.  I would like to improve on the idea of keeping copies of whole images before each modification to allow for undo.  I'm not sure if it would be any more efficient (memory and speed), but I'm thinking maybe it would be better to only save the changed pixels instead of the whole image.  The comparison is simple enough, just do a bit-wise comparison of the original and the modified image.  The idea is to recover by replacing the modified pixels with the stored originals.

But would I still end up storing a full-sized image with only changes?
Or is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: I should add, this would be for cases where only a small portion of the image was modified, where storing the whole image would be inefficient.

Comment: I think it depends on the format of the image you are storing...

Comment: Do you really want to keep several "copies" or a single copy for a single undo would do the job (after each modifications)?

Comment: If the color depth is 256 or lower, the GIF file format reveals a lossless compressed "difference between images" technique, usually used for animated gifs.  For high-color images, nearly any video codec will describe a lossy compression technique.  Describing either would require more than a few paragraphs though.

Comment: Instead of storing different versions of the image, how about storing a sequence/list of operations and their parameters? Applying these operations in the order they are stored, yields the current version of the image. An "undo" would mean to remove the last list item and to render again.

Comment: Based on what I've read here, GIMP and Photoshop store a copy of the image at each modification, so if you undo back to point x, you use the image saved at point x.  Yes, storing a list of changes is also an option.   Each has its obvious advantages and disadvantages.  Storing copies of the whole image is faster, but is a memory hog.  Storing the actual changes and repeating them up to x is far better for memory, but for huge images (say, a 24 MP DLSR image) could be very slow to apply.  What I'm hoping I can do is a compromise:  save the diffs.  But in cases where the whole image changes.....